# MVC 3 - Image upload fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying write a program that allows users add a image to a database, but it fails. I would be grateful if someone could help me...
My Index.cshtml file has the following code...

```
 <td>
   @item.Picture1
   <img alt="@Html.Encode(item.Picture1)" src='@(Url.Action(("Picture1")) + 
    ToString())' width="64" height="64" />
</td>
```

Create.cshtml file looks like this...

```
<div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture1)
      <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" size="23"/>
      @Html.ValidationMessage("Picture1", "*")
</div>
<p>
     <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

In the controller, for Create, I have the following code...

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "SubProductCategoryID")] SubProductCategory2 Createsubcat2, FormCollection values)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
             Createsubcat2.Picture1 = (new FileHandler()).uploadedFileToByteArray((HttpPostedFileBase)Request.Files[0]);
            }
            db.AddToSubProductCategory2(Createsubcat2);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("/");
        }
        PopulateProductCategoryDropDownList(Createsubcat2.ProductCategoryID);
        return View(Createsubcat2);
    }

    public FileResult Image(int id)
    {
        const string alternativePicturePath = @"/Content/question_mark.jpg";
        SubProductCategory2 product = db.SubProductCategory2.Where(k => k.SubProductCategoryID == id).FirstOrDefault();

        MemoryStream stream;

        if (product != null && product.Picture1 != null)
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream(product.Picture1);
        }
        else // If product cannot be found or product doesn't have a picture
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream();

            var path = Server.MapPath(alternativePicturePath);
            var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(path);

            image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

FileHandler.cs

```
public class FileHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a HttpPostedFileBase into a byte array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public byte[] uploadedFileToByteArray(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        int nFileLen = file.ContentLength;
        byte[] result = new byte[nFileLen];

        file.InputStream.Read(result, 0, nFileLen);

        return result;
    }
```

Thanks in advance. I am using http://blog-dotnet.com/category/ASPNET-MVC.aspx website for reference. I am using VS 2010, ASP.NET 4.0, MVC 3 in C#. SQL Server 2008R2. SubProductCategory2 table has file Picture1, image data type.

> **Edit:**
>   Actually working on more I have public byte[] Picture1 { get; set; } in one of the classes. The output I am now getting is System.Byte[] System.Byte[]. How do I fix this?

Comment: what fails? You have code, but nothing to describe what error / issue you are experiencing

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get an error?

Comment: There is no error when running the application. When I browse to find a picture and then click on Create, the page will go back to Index where no picture is shown only the text that has been entered by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as having an input with a type of file, you need to make sure your form accepts multipart data...

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
```

I couldn't see your form element to confirm whether you had done this.

Comment: Hi Sohnee where do I need code that in the @using (Html.BeginForm())

Comment: Actually working on more I have  public byte[] Picture1 { get; set; } in one of the classes. The output I am now getting is System.Byte[] System.Byte[]. How do I fix this?

Comment: Because I am recieving error System.Byte[]  and a different problem to this thread. Also that nobody responded back. I will ask a new question. So I hope the mod's won't mind. Thanks